# Am I supposed to be one-shotting non-elder dragons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My character's only level 38 and have not advanced very much on the main quest line yet (I blame Smithing and Enchanting :)). Only just came out of High Hrothgar and didn't complete their trial yet.

I explore in the south west area on the way to Falkreath, which I didn't uncover yet on the map. Two times I stumbled upon a "Dragon" (just the basic name, not an Elder variant). Each time when it finally landed, I hit it just once and it died immediately.

My character has a 68-ish damage Glass Mace, but even so, the other Dragons I've encountered take at least five power attacks, usually around ten before they die.

Those Dragons were no fun at all and so I'm wondering if this is an known issue maybe with the level scaling?

Can you somehow fix the level scaling for Dragons when going somewhere and coming back later, even if upon your first exploration no dragons were present?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are just too strong for some of them. I began following the main quest line as soon as I started the game. My difficulty level is either Normal or Hard, I forget which. I fought my first dragons at level 4 ~ 6, maybe even earlier. My damage at around that time was less than 20. I've come across random ones while on my way to complete various quest that were not that strong. Me and my follower took them out very easily.

So it is no surprise that you can one shot a dragon, as it could be one that is meant for a level 6 to fight.

Also note that brown and green dragons are weaker dragons compared to their red and black.

That, or there is a bug in the game.

Comment: When I slayed my first dragon, I thought I was the shiznit. Then the next one that appeared out of no where handed me by azz on a platter. Really put me in my place.

Comment: I've fought about fifteen dragons so far. The last two I met were one-shot kills, hence my surprise. EDIT: True, those were plain vanilla "Dragons". Hopefully it's just a level scaling glitch in the lower level areas.

Answer (score 3):

Try increasing the difficulty of the game under settings.